# Evaluate the integrals in terms of inverse hyperbolic functions & natural logs

Tags: definite-integrals, logarithms, hyperbolic-functions

Having trouble with my homework. It is asking evaluate the integral in terms of 1) inverse hyperbolic function and 2) natural logarithm

The integral is $$ \int_0^{2\sqrt3} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{4+x^2}} $$

I would also post what I have so far, but I don't have anything :/ Any help would be very very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sqrt{4+x^2} = \sqrt 4 \cdot \sqrt{1+ \left( \frac x 2 \right)^2}.
$$

When you see "$1+(\cdots)^2$", you think of a certain trigonometric substitution.

(And when you see "$1-(\cdots)^2$", you think of a certain other trigonometric substitution.)

(And when you see "$(\cdots)^2 -1$", you think of a certain other trigonometric substitution.)

**PS:** Alright, let's pursue this:
\begin{align}
\frac x 2 & = \tan\theta \\[10pt]
\frac{dx} 2 & = \sec^2\theta\,d\theta \\[10pt]
1 + \tan^2\theta & = \sec^2\theta
\end{align}
When $\theta=0$ then $x=0$, and when $\theta=\pi/3$ then $x=2 \sqrt 3$. So
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\sqrt 3} \frac{dx/2}{\sqrt{1 + (x/2)^2}} & = \int_0^{\pi/3} \frac{\sec^2\theta\,d\theta}{\sec\theta} = \int_0^{\pi/3} \sec\theta\,d\theta \\[10pt]
& = \left. \log(\sec\theta+\tan\theta) \vphantom{\frac 1 1} \right|_0^{\pi/3} = \log(2+\sqrt 3).
\end{align}

Is this the same as $\sinh^{-1}\sqrt3\,{}$?  Let's check:
$$
\sinh\log(2+\sqrt3) = \frac{e^{\log(2+\sqrt 3)} + e^{-(\log(2+\sqrt 3))}} 2 = \frac {2+\sqrt 3 - \frac 1 {2+\sqrt 3}} 2.
$$
By rationalizing the denominator we find that this is the same as
$$
\frac {(2+\sqrt 3) - (2-\sqrt 3)} 2 = \sqrt 3.
$$
So it checks.

Comment: How do you get $\frac x2$ ? Wouldn't it be $\frac x4$since you are taking 4 from the expression?

Comment: @bankey : $\dfrac{x^2} 4 = \left( \dfrac x 2 \right)^2$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Ahh so you are just manipulating it a little further...this is so tough for me, I would never think to manipulate the expression these ways

Comment: I am still not understanding how to get the answer of $ sinh^{-1} \sqrt3 $ .. what I got was $  dx / (2sinh^{-1} * \frac x2 ^ 2)$

Answer (score 0):

**method 1**: $$u = \sqrt{4+x^2} \to u^2 = 4+x^2 \to x^2 = u^2-4\to x = \sqrt{u^2-4}\to 2u\,du = 2x\,dx\to u\,du = x\,dx\to I = \int_2^4 \dfrac{du}{\sqrt{u^2-4}}.$$ From here we can put $u = 2\cosh(v)$

**method 2**:

put $x = 2\tan(u)$

**method 3**:

put $x = 2\sinh(u)$

Comment: Not exactly sure what all those methods mean.. The answer from the back of the book is $ sinh^{-1} (\sqrt 3  $ for the inverse hyperbolic function, and $ ln (\sqrt 3 + 2)  $

Comment: These are just partial answers or hints, and you should work them out to the end to get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Substitute $x=2\cosh \theta$